# Ember Integration Test: Promise rejected before it renders

Tags: javascript, ember.js, qunit, ember-qunit

Strange error started occurring in my Ember.js (2.2) application.  I created a new component that uses a global library (e.g. Bloodhound). Suddenly some of my other UNRELATED/UNTOUCHED component integration tests stopped working, returning the following error: `Promise rejected before it renders: Assertion Failed: You cannot use the same root element (#ember-testing) multiple times in an Ember.Application`

I don't know if this is some sort of race-condition or threading issue while executing my tests using `ember test`.  Very strange.

I'm currently trying to figure out how to deal with my global library situation, this is an existing & recently updated app...I can't make enormous changes right now.  And I certainly can't abandon this new component because it was needed...what to do?

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to remedy my global library situation, I started invoking the library as `window.Bloodhound` within my *new* Component.  This has apparently cured my other tests that stopped working.  I hope this bit of insight helps.

Once I track down the ACTUAL error/issue, I'll either raise a ticket or report the correction here.